# Is it possible to reset a scanner to the first line of text, after it has iterate through the whole file?

Tags: java, file, io, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to print both the tongueTwister text into the command Prompt and the tongueTwisterOutput.txt. I know that I can do both within the same while loop. However I was wondering if it is possible to reset the scanner so that it can start reading from the first line again?

```
while(in.hasNextLine())
{

    System.out.println("/* " + number + " */" + in.nextLine());
    number++;
}
in.reset();
while(in.hasNextLine())
{
    printer.print(in.nextLine() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Resetting the scanner does not reset the underlying stream. You have to do that yourself, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed to do.You have to declare a new `Scanner` because it doesn't support reseting.